# fs.readFileSync is not a function Meteor, React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, meteor, npm, fs

I'm getting a 'fs.readFileSync is not a function' in Chrome debugger after trying to call readFileSync();

I call it...

```
const fs = require('fs');
```

call the function...

```
let content = fs.readFileSync('/path/to/my/file.stuff');
```

And attempt to display content..

```
console.log(content);
```

I get nothing. When I do...

```
console.log(fs);
```

I appear to get a generic javascript object...
I'm completely stuck.

Meteor version: 1.5.1
npm version: 3.10.10
node version: v6.10.1

Comment: is that mistake on the require call present in your code as well?

Comment: No, that was a typo in my post. Sorry. That's not the problem.

Comment: what is the type of file? what kind of data your are reading from file?

Comment: it's actually a custom .info file. It just has data in each line that needs to be split up into an array.

Comment: is it running on the client or server ?

Comment: I'm running in locally. The file is under the meteor project directory.

Comment: I mean you can only use this library in node environment, when the code is running on the server side. Like the window object is available on the browser only. You can't read a file directly from the browser that way.

Answer (score 23):

Thanks for all the answers!

I have confirmed that you cannot use fs on the client side.

Instead, I made another local simple express node api and the react web app just makes a request back to the node api to get that data.

Also, you have to do this...

https://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html

EDIT:

Wrote this a long time ago. 3 years back when I was just starting my web development learning. Just want to update and say that there is a serious fundamental difference between what the user sees and what the server sees. Allowing the front-end (Meteor, React, Angular, etc.) to read files would be a super serious security issue. Anyone could make a website that when a user goes to it, it would just read your local computers files. Not good...

While this is super obvious to me now, it wasn't obvious 3 years ago. So for all you newbies out there, it's okay :) No question is a dumb question.

Answer (score 7):

> I'm getting a 'fs.readFileSync is not a function' in Chrome debugger after trying to call readFileSync();

`fs` will not work in the browser. This is by design as to protect your filesystem from potential security threats.

#### Using low level Node packages in a browser environment

If you need access to this in a browser environment, consider making use of [Electron](https://electron.atom.io/) which allows you to make use of OS level NodeJS packages in a running instance of Chromium.

Answer (score 1):

`fs` cannot be used on the client, due to browsers restricting some javascript code.

If your code is being run on both the server and client, you can use:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) return;
```

to avoid the error. Otherwise, there should be another way to do what you're trying to accomplish, such as `import`ing required JSON.