# How to read file on client side in meteorjs?

Tags: node.js, meteor

Im new to meteor and nodejs. I'm developing an application in meteor where I need to read private key (Privatekey.pem) file from a directory on local machine. As this private key will be used buy client to sign some data. I need the client to read that private key and sign the data. I have already tried

fs.readFileSync('Privatekey.pem');

But it fails as you can't use "fs" on client side [fs.readFileSync is not a function Meteor, React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45466848/fs-readfilesync-is-not-a-function-meteor-react) . So please guide me that how can I read the file on client side.

Comment: Which frontend do you use? Blaze, React, Vue, Angular?

Comment: @Jankapunkt Blaze

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily leverage the [`FileReader` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) in combination with a input of type file:

```html
<template name="myReader">
  <input type="file" id="my-file-input" />
</template>
```

Now on this template you "listen" to the `change` event of `my-file-input` using [Blaze event maps](http://blazejs.org/api/templates.html#Event-Maps):

```js
Template.myReader.events({
  'change #my-file-input' (event, templateInstance) {
    const file = event.currentTarget.files[ 0 ]
    const reader = new FileReader()
    reader.onload = function () {
      const text = reader.result
      // do Meteor.call() or
      // add it to a reactive variable
      // on your templateInstance
    }
    reader.readAsText(file)
  },
})
```

Comment: Thanks @jankapunkt . I have tried by adding file path manually as I dont need blaze even cz it has to get file on its own. const file = '/home/zaid/Desktop/MeteorNew/MeteorProject/meteor/Public/rsa_1024_pub.pem'; But its fails with an error "Argumant1 of readAsText function is not an object"