# How to set up dynamic environment configurations in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, configuration, environment-variables, dotenv

My aim is to find a way to dynamically pull in environment-specific config values for various 'tracks' of my React app: development, staging and production. The solution most often prescribed involves the use of environment variables, which I don't find great because:

1. Some of my config values are sensitive data like API secret keys, database passwords, etc and I'd ***ideally*** not be keeping these in plain-text both locally and on a CICD system
2. Having to manually set env vars is error prone and doesn't scale well (it's a big project that has more than 20 config-related key-value pairs to set). It's also difficult to document which env vars need to be set, so it's not a convenient solution for a multi-collaborator team as everyone needs to keep track of the list and copy-paste the values into their local machines for shared API keys, etc (or worse, hard-coding/checking them into the source code)

I have tried the following 2 general approaches:

1. Use [node-config](https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config) - it looks promising as it's light, flexible, and extensible (it allows defining base values on `default.js` and overriding them with `development.js`, `staging.js`, `production.js` or with custom env variables). Most importantly, we **can store secrets in a remote service** (e.g AWS/GCP Secrets Manager, [envkey](https://www.envkey.com/), etc). This solution works well for my Node backend, but so far not for the frontend app built on React
2. Use [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv) (or [dotenv-safe](https://github.com/rolodato/dotenv-safe), to allow documenting the structure of .env file in another one `.env.example` that is checked into source control). This is not my favored approach as dotenv [discourages using multiple .env files](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#should-i-have-multiple-env-files) for each environment our project needs. Secondly, I'd likely still have to find another way to feed in the env variables into my CICD system. Redefining the env vars on the [remote] build system feels like doing the work twice - the first being on the .env files used for local development.

Both approaches yield a familiar problem: `TypeError: fs.readFileSync is not a function`. According to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45466848/1145905), it appears that the underlying issue is that [the 'fs' module is not designed to work on the browser](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv/issues/323#issuecomment-403070289) (both dotenv and node-config are low level modules that use 'fs' under the hood). **If we cannot use fs (or rather, modules that rely on it) on the client side: how do scalable/production-grade React projects typically manage config values in a sane way?** I know [hashicorp/vault](https://github.com/hashicorp/vault) exists but it seems a bit of an overkill as we'd likely have to set up our own infrastructure.

I also wonder if there's any open-source tools out there to solve this common problem...

Comment: Create multiple .env file in addition to the basic one. Like .env.dev .env.stage .env.prod. when you create the build, or you start it, pass an env variable through. Command line specifying the env. Then before to build or start, copy the content of the corresponding env file of that evn, into the main .env file. React should pick up correctly the right bones env resilient

Comment: @quirimmo I was hoping to avoid copy-pasting between .env files. Anyway, I found a better solution based on Doppler

Answer (score 3):

Neither of the two solutions offered above really met my requirements, first because I'm using a create-react-app project so don't have much control over webpack configuration. Secondly, I'd much prefer to not keep `.env` files locally (let alone in plain text)

Luckily, I came across https://doppler.com/, a universal secrets management solution that solves my needs as described on the OP:

1. it's a cloud-based secrets store + manager that comes with a CLI, which allows us to use the same env secrets across the entire pipeline (local development, CICD and production)
2. projects come loaded with development, staging and production environments that makes it easy to switch easily between different flavors of the app

Because Doppler works by injecting environment variables into the runtime, I can run it like so, with yarn:

`doppler run --  yarn start`

For server environments that need to first inject the env vars into a bundled app (e.g the firebase emulator), first do a 'doppler-injected' build:

`doppler run -- yarn build`

And then run the emulator as usual:
`firebase emulators:start`

Answer (score 0):

Using separate `dotenv` for example, `.env.dev` , `.env.qa` would be my current approach to a scalable react project. I am assuming you are using `webpack` and are facing issues in fetching the files using `fs`, as separately `fs` is a node server side module.
To resolve this `TypeError` issue, in your `webpack` config, you can use `fs` to access the current working directory,

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const reactAppDirectory = fs.realpathSync(process.cwd());
const resolveReactApp = (relativePath) => path.resolve(reactAppDirectory, relativePath);
```

You need to copy all your assets and build into a spearate `public` folder have a web.config  and resolve its path using the above `resolveReactApp('public')` in `contentBase` key of `devServer` section of your `webpack` config.

You can pass the environment variables using webpack's DefinePlugin or EnvironmentPlugin,

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV),
  'process.env.DEBUG': JSON.stringify(process.env.DEBUG)
});

new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin(['NODE_ENV', 'DEV']);
```

To store secrets, I would suggest you check out docker-secrets and using a containerized architecture for deployment, and further when the team expands, it'll be easier to get the project setup as well. Here's a quick setup intro of [how to use docker with react](https://medium.com/better-programming/heres-how-you-can-use-docker-with-create-react-app-3ee3a972b04e) and more info on [switching from environment variables to docker-secrets](https://medium.com/lucjuggery/from-env-variables-to-docker-secrets-bc8802cacdfd) for a better system architecture.

Comment: Great insights, though I wasn't able to pursue this path as I don't have control over webpack config - I'm using a CRA app

Comment: @kip2 Look in to [craco](https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco). It allows you to extend CRA without ejecting